# Spark: passing broadcast variable to executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast

I am passing a broadcast variable to all my executors using the following code. The code seems to work, but I don't know if my approach is good enough. Just want to see if anyone has any better suggestions. Thank you very much!

```
val myRddMap = sc.textFile("input.txt").map(t => myParser.parse(t))
val myHashMapBroadcastVar = sparkContext.broadcast(myRddMap.collect().toMap)
```

where `myRddMap` is of type  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String))]`

Then I have a utility function which I pass in RDDs and variables like:

```
val myOutput = myUtiltityFunction.process(myRDD1, myHashMapBroadcastVar)
```

---

So is above code a good way for handling broadcast variables? Or is there any better approach? Thanks!

Comment: Looks all right to me. One remark: if the data fits on one machine (it does if you can `collect` it) then it is not necessary to load it into an RDD. You could load and parse it without Spark and avoid some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.

Broadcast variables are actually sent to all nodes. So it doesn't matter that you use those in a utility function, or anywhere. As for as I think you are doing the right thing, nothing seems wrong that resulted in a poor performance.