# spark broadcast isn't being saved at the executors memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used spark-shell on EMR - Spark version 2.2.0 / 2.1.0.
While trying to broadcast simple object (my CSV file contain only 1 column and it's less then 2 MB) I noticed it isn't being kept on each executor memory and just in the driver memory although it should be as suggested in the documentation [https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-TorrentBroadcast.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBrys.png)

Attached print screen before the broadcast (i.e. sc.broadcast(arr_collected) ) and after the broadcast which shows my conclusion. Additionally I checked the worker's machine memory usage and same as in Spark UI, it's not being change after the broadcasting.

1- [print screen before broadcast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBrys.png)

2- [print screen after broadcast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPBV.png)

Attached the log for the broadcasting process after adding 'log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager=TRACE' like suggested here - 
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-blockmanager.html

3- [print screen broadcast logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urPQU.png)

Below there is the code -

```
val input  = "s3://bucketName/pathToFile.csv"
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load(input)
val df_2 = df_read_for_bc.withColumn("is_exist",lit("true").cast("Boolean"))
val arr_collected = df_2.collect()

val broadcast_map_fraud_locations4 = sc.broadcast(arr_collected)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the broadcast varialables to join the data or do some kind of operation. It might be lazy so not using any memory

Comment: You are right, there is an explanation of 'Anatomy of how broadcast works' here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754123/apache-spark-how-to-structure-code-of-a-spark-application-especially-when-usin?rq=1